# Laravel get checkbox value dynamically

Tags: php, html, laravel, checkbox, pagination

i have a collection of data paginated through the method paginate ().
Inside the blade i print my data, and for every line there is a checkbox (each has an univocal name).
The problem is that if i change page i lose the checks.
how can i save these checks through the paginazione? or other methods?
To save the checks I use a submit.

**Blade**

```
 @foreach($data as $d)
     <tr>
         <td>
             {!! Form::checkbox($sub->id, '1', null) !!}
         </td>
         <td>{{$d->hello}}</td>
          ...
     </tr>
 @endforeach
```

**pagination**

```
 <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-12" align="center">
         {{ $data->appends(request()->query())->links() }}
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: I think you should use session.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use javascript and ajax to do this. Every time you navigate to another page, a new GET request is sent to the server and every checkbox that has been changed will be forgotten.

Depending on what those checkboxes should do, your best option is to add javascript to the page that sends a request to the server whenever a value is changed. This way you can let the server react to this event.

Comment: yes i know, but i wanna know if someone have found other ways